# Lens flare in 2D XNA 4.0 scene

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, flare

I am creating realtime scene in XNA, it is 2D using sprites only (rendered on quads, standard spritebatch with alpha map on sprites). I would like to create create simply lens flare, actually only occlusion around light source (I don´t need direction to center of camera to offset multiple sprites for lens flare, etc.) Only thing I basically need is to calculate how many pixels from light source sprite (small star) are rendered and according to it set scale of lens flare sprite (so scale 0 if sprite there are not visible pixels from relevant sprite).

I know how to do it in 3D, I read through this and tested few things:
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/game-programming/9781849691987/1dot-applying-special-effects/id286698039

I would like to ask what is best and cheapest way to do it in 2D scene (counting how many pixels of sprite were rendered / occluded with per pixel precision or something  comparable).

I know also stencil buffer could help but I am not sure how to applicate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, two ways how to solve it, either kinda old school approach, using stencil to calculate count of occluded pixels and scale sprites of lens flare according to it.

Other way: modern approach, use screen space lens flare, isolate bright pixels (I recommend HDR rendering pipeline and use values of brightness above 1.0 to generate lens flares, but it depends on scene average and maximum) and generate ghosts, like so:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_A0nKfzbs80&list=UUywPlxpmCZtuqOs6_bZEG9A